# Changing Timestamp conversion to a Function

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime, ccxt

I'm working with some CCXT data and I have converted the Timestamp to Datetime by using:

```
df['Timestamp'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='ms'))
```

Now I'm trying to turn that conversion into a function, modeled after this one:

```
def datetime_parse_timestamp (time_in_secs):    
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time_in_secs))
```

So it can be called as

```
df = pd.read_csv('binance-BTCUSDT-4h.csv', parse_dates=True, date_parser=datetime_parse_timestamp, index_col='Timestamp')
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably need to do something like:

```
def datetime_parse_timestamp(time_in_secs):
   return pd.to_datetime(time_in_secs,unit='ms')
```

Credit: You

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the timestamp as a difference from current time you can use datetime.timedelta as

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime

>>> a=1549032022
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-a))
'4 days, 15:20:38.691180'
```

otherwise you already have the answer and if you want any modification in your answer you can use lambda function as per your ease.